# Reporting Services loses Oracle Datasource connection on deployed reports. Test Datasource connections works fine

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g, datasource, ssrs-2012

On my deployed reports that use an Oracle Datasource my reports come up with a cannot connect to the datasource error with ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.  TNS record is fine and when I test the Datasource from the deployment is tests successful and I can run a single query report at least one time before getting the same error.  My reports that run multiple queries always give the error.  I do have both the 32 and 64 bit Oracle pieces installed.  Any thoughts are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved on my own.  Recreating the datasource from the web interface and changing the report datasources to the newly created datasource resolved the issues